# Reposition camera to object & lookAt() (React three fiber)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

I am trying to transition `camera.position` and `camera.lookAt` smoothly between "zoomed out" and "zoomed in" views of individual, randomly placed objects.

The positioning works great. Lerping the `lookAt()`, however, doesn't seem to be playing nicely with other solutions for traditional ThreeJS ( see @bovesan's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65222248/1156938)) nor addressed by the relevant example on the react-three-fiber docs ([link](https://codesandbox.io/s/camera-pan-nsb7f)).

Zooming in past the z axis flips the camera around, and at the corners it's wildly distored.

You can see my progress here : https://codesandbox.io/s/three-fiber-zoom-to-object-rlme0?file=/src/App.js

With the relevant bit of code being in `App.js` on line 63 :

```js
 useFrame((state) => {
    const step = 0.05;

    // `focus` is a state variable that sends a Vec3 of the objects position
    zoom ? vec.set(focus.x, focus.y, focus.z + 0.2) : vec.set(0, 0, 5);

    // HERE, looking for a way to lerp camera lookAt in a way that can toggle.
    state.camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    state.camera.position.lerp(vec, step);

    state.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });
```

I've spent hours looking for relevant examples/tutorials, but haven't come up with much. I'm afraid I don't have enough ThreeJs experience to be looking in the right direction, though, so any help in any direction would be most welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To anyone who happens upon this later, the solution was figured out over at by @drcmda.

You can find a working example here :

https://codesandbox.io/s/three-fiber-zoom-to-object-camera-controls-solution-final-sbgx0?file=/src/App.js

This is just a slight change on @drcmda 's implementation of [camera-controls](https://github.com/yomotsu/camera-controls) with normal lerping to move the camera. It’s not perfect (for one, the transition time in camera controls doesn’t seem to be editable, so there’s a weird swing-around thing that happens, when you’re zooming back out) but it definitely solves the problem. (Many thanks to @looeee and @forerunrun for additional help.)

If you'd rather not use another library, @forerunrun's answer in [the original thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/lerping-camera-and-lookat-together-with-dynamic-taret-react-three-fiber/28896/13) also works well, but I wasn't able to debug it enough to have it be reliable. (See convo.)